# Null when trying to put ImageView in adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to put an image view in adapter.

I'm trying to do this because I saw an example of putting *TextView* in ArrayAdapter, like this :

```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, transmit_noktp_list) {
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);         
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);     
            return view;
         }
      };
```

So derived from the example, then I tried to put *ImageView* also to achieve icon & text on each list item :

So tried :

```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, transmit_noktp_list) {
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon1);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            Resources resources = getResources();
            img.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inbox));

            return view;
         }
      };
```

suprisingly this    *`img.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inbox));`* line throwed me an exception (I can assured that '***inbox***' icon is in `res/drawable`, it's even showed in my IDE) :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs, PID: 24855
>                                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                               at
>   com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.DaftarAspirasiFragment$1.getView(DaftarAspirasiFragment.java:55)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1768)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5694)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
 img.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inbox));
```

Try  `img.setImageResource(R.drawable.inbox)`;

Comment: It produces same error